# How can I appropriately prove something in a proof(in other words, make a subproof) and refer back to it later in the proof

Tags: proof-writing

I am relatively new to number theory, and wanted to ask how to appropriately write a “subproof” within a proof. I searched the internet for a solution and came across “lemmas” but am not sure if I can create my own lemma within a proof and refer to it later. Any help would be appreciated:

Let’s say I need to prove that a number x satisfies the inequality 8 < x < 12

Is there a way I can prove this by writing a proof that goes something like this:

Subproof 1(proves x < 12):
*blablabla random proof stuff…* that results in: x < 12

Subproof 2(proves x > 8):
*blablabla random proof stuff…* that results in x > 8

Then have a final statement: “due to subproof 1 and subproof 2: 8 < x < 12”

Comment: check out any standard textbook in analysis or number theory. They'll have examples of how to write like this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with number theory. Of course, $x<12$ and $x>8$ will give $8<x<12$. What means that "$x$ is a number"? Is it an integer? Is it just a real number?  I suppose this is rather calculus than number theory.

Comment: You can use paragraphs and natural language to structure the overall proof and separate the subproofs. If you're working on a larger project you may want to number the theorems as you go to refer back to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For smaller proofs, you could write something like

> *Proof.* First, we prove that $x < 12$. [*proof that $x < 12$*].
>
> Next, we prove that $x > 8. $ [*proof that $x > 8$*].
>
> Therefore $8 < x < 12$. $\square$

For a larger proof, typically the "subcase" is its own separate lemma that is proven before the main theorem. For a lemma within a proof, the following format is an option (and certainly not the only option):

> **Theorem.** [*some statement*]
>
> *Proof.* [*a partial proof*]
>
> We will now need the following lemma:
>
> **Lemma.** [*lemma statement*]
>
> *Proof of lemma.* [*the proof of the lemma*] $\square$
>
> Now we return to the proof of the theorem. [*completes proof of theorem*] $\square$

Generally speaking, as long as other readers can read your proof without much difficulty, you're fine.

Comment: The way you formatted your answer was extremely extremely helpful and clarified this for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One question- For the longer proof format you gave, what if I want to use the lemma again later in the proof? Would I have to reprove the lemma?

Comment: @ShauryaJeevagan You'd label the lemma, e.g. calling it "Lemma 1". You can then refer to it as Lemma 1 in other proofs.

Comment: Usually one will write something more along the lines of, "[...] but before we prove Theorem X, we need the following lemma Y". I haven't yet seen a textbook that interrupts a proof to first state a lemma.

Comment: @soggycornflakes Yeah it is much more common in textbooks to prove all necessary lemmas first before doing the proof of the big theorem. I have seen lemmas interrupt proofs in some papers though.

Comment: The way you write out a proof formally doesn't have to match the process you went through when finding the proof, either. It's likely that you start trying stuff, then half-way through realise "I need to prove this intermediate result" and take care of that. But when you write the proof out, you would turn that result into a lemma and put it at the start of the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you only operate in natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}$. IMHO, $8 < x < 12$ is just an abbreviation for there exists an $x$ such that $8 < x \land x < 12$. That is, $(\exists x)(p(8, x) \land p(x, 12))$, where the predicate $p$ is interpreted as the "$<$" relation.

IMHO, if you want to write in formal first order logic, the proof would look something like this:

1. $\vdash (\exists x)p(8, x)$ (assume you proved it above)
2. $\vdash (\exists x)p(x, 12)$ (assume you proved it above)
3. $\vdash p(8, a)$ (C-Rule)
4. $\vdash p(a, 12)$ (C-Rule)
5. $\vdash p(8, a) \land p(a, 12)$ (AND introduction)
6. $\vdash (\exists x)(p(8, x) \land p(x, 12)$ (Converse of C-Rule)

Then it is formally proved.

(I'm also not sure with the procedure; Any corrections are welcomed!)

Comment: I doubt OP was looking for a first-order logic proof ;)

Comment: haha yeah. most of these symbols make no sense to me but I picked up a number theory book today and hope that I can understand this response in a few months ;)